# Array entries, and incrementing a counter according to rules in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method in java that will increment a counter for each time one of the following rules is satisfied when iterating through an array.

1) Two adjacent values in an array equal each other and the first value in each pair starts at an even numbered index value (0,2,4...etc)

2) For all adjacent pairs of entries, the values of one pair equal the values of the next pair and length(adjacent pairs of entries) mod 2 = 0
So 0,0,0,0,1,1 satisfies this rule but 0,0,0,1 does not (there are only 3 0's which violates the last condition)

So far I have this, which implements the first rule:

```
public class ArrayEvaluate {

public static double evaluate(int[] array)
{
    double  ruleSat = 0;
      for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++){

            if((array[index] == array[index + 1]) &&(index%2==0)){
                ruleSat++;
            }
}
return ruleSat;
}
 public static void main(final String[] args){

int[] array = new int[6];
array[0]= 1;
array[1]=1;
array[2]=3;
array[3]=3;
array[4]=4;
array[5]=4;

evaluate(array);
 }
}
```

However, this does not work completely, and I'm not sure how to go about the second rule.

Thanks

Comment: I bet he gets an index out of bounds on the last iteration because of:  'if((array[index] == array[index + 1])'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double evaluate(int[] array) {
    double ruleSat = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (index != array.length-1) {
            if ((array[index] == array[index + 1]) && (index % 2 == 0)) {
                ruleSat++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ruleSat;
}
```

This will prevent the index out of bounds error your receiving

**Update for second rule:**
This separates the logic for rule 1 and rule 2 so if you ever need to change a rule individually they are independent.

public class ArrayEvaluate {

```
public static double evaluate(int[] array) {
    double something = 0;
    int rule1Occurences = testRule1(array);
    int rule2Occurences = testRule2(array);
    System.out.println(rule1Occurences);
    System.out.println(rule2Occurences);
    return something;//not sure how rules relate
}
//This counts when array element == next array element
public static int testRule1(int[] array){
    int ruleSat = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (index != array.length - 1) {
            if ((array[index] == array[index + 1]) && (index % 2 == 0)) {
                ruleSat++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ruleSat;     
}
//This blocks the pairs off in sets of two disregarding any odd parings
public static int testRule2(int[] array)
{
    int rule2Sat = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if(index <= array.length - 4){
            if (array[index] + array[index+1] == array[index+2] + array[index+3]) {
                rule2Sat++;
            }
        }
    }
    return rule2Sat;    
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    int[] dataSet = new int[6];
    dataSet[0] = 0;
    dataSet[1] = 0;
    dataSet[2] = 0;
    dataSet[3] = 0;
    dataSet[4] = 4;
    dataSet[5] = 4;

    System.out.println(evaluate(dataSet));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you say its not homework, this is what I would do

```
public class ArrayEvaluate {
    public static int evaluate(int... array) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i += 2)
            if(array[i] == array[i + 1]) { // rule one
               counter++; 
               if (i < array.length-3 && 
                     array[i] == array[i + 2] && 
                     array[i + 2] == array[i + 3]) // rule two
                  counter++;
            }
        return counter;
    }


  public static void main(String... args){
    int test1 = evaluate(1,2,3,3,4,4);
    assert test1 == 2;
    int test2 = evaluate(0,0,0,0,1,1);
    assert test1 == 4;
    int test2 = evaluate(0,0,0,1,1,1);
    assert test1 == 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: For test1 the assert test1 should equal 2 because only 3,3 and 4,4 are satisfied and in the last test, it should also be 2 because only the 0,0 at the beginnig and the 1,1 at the end are satisfied

Comment: Also the second rule should match entries of any even size >2 not just 4

Comment: If its an even size greater than 4 you only need to check the first 4.  It would only make a difference if you wanted one pair to mean +1, two pair means +3 (2 pair and one quadruple), three pair means +6 (three pair, two quadruple and one lot of six) four pair means +10, etc.